# Jbutton issues within my code

Tags: java, swing, flash, button

i have been working on a flashing beacon on java using Jpanel, paint component and timers, however i am having trouble trying to get the buttons within the code to function. when the code is run, the flash button is supposed to prompt the beacon to start blinking/flashing whereas the steady button keeps it on the same colour. the alternating colours for the beacon are orange and grey.As well as this i cant seem to get rid of a button that keeps appearing in the top left of the window when the code is run. so far, this is what i have

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
/**
 * Created by Enoch on 26/03/2015.
 */

class BelishaBeacon extends JPanel {
    Color startLight, stopLight, color;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(color);
        Ellipse2D firstOval = new Ellipse2D.Double(130, 70, 50, 50);
        g2.draw(firstOval);
        g2.fill(firstOval);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(150, 119, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect1);
        g2.fill(rect1);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(150, 150, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect2);
        g2.fill(rect2);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(150, 180, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect3);
        g2.fill(rect3);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(150, 210, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect4);
        g2.fill(rect4);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect5 = new Rectangle(150, 240, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect5);
        g2.fill(rect5);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle rect6 = new Rectangle(150, 270, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect6);
        g2.fill(rect6);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect7 = new Rectangle(150, 300, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect7);
        g2.fill(rect7);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle rect8 = new Rectangle(150, 330, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect8);
        g2.fill(rect8);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect9 = new Rectangle(150, 360, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect9);
        g2.fill(rect9);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Rectangle rect10 = new Rectangle(150, 390, 10, 35);
        g2.draw(rect10);
        g2.fill(rect10);
    }

    public BelishaBeacon() {
        startLight = Color.ORANGE;
        stopLight = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        color = startLight;
        new Blinker(this);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void blink()
    {
        color = (color == startLight ? stopLight : startLight);
        repaint();
    }
}
//
class Blinker
{
    BelishaBeacon blinkPanel;

    public Blinker(BelishaBeacon bp)
    {
        blinkPanel = bp;
        new Timer(500, new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                blinkPanel.blink();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
//
class BelishaBeaconViewer extends JFrame {
    JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
    JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
    JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
    BelishaBeacon bBPanel = new BelishaBeacon();

    public BelishaBeaconViewer() {
        bPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        this.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bPanel.add(jbtSteady);
        this.add(bBPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jbtFlash.addActionListener(new FlashListener());
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(new SteadyListener());


    }

    class FlashListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    class SteadyListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame bBFrame = new BelishaBeaconViewer();
        bBFrame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        bBFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        bBFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation((JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));
        bBFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise repainted was not required.

Answer (score 1):

> i cant seem to get rid of a button that keeps appearing in the top left of the window

```
//super.paintComponents(g); // typo
super.paintComponent(g); // should be
```

Don't start the Timer automatically.

1. The FlashListener should start the Timer, no need for the repaint
2. The SteadyListner should stop the Timer, no need for the repaint.